# Свёртачные нейроные сети python

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, tensorflow

У меня появился вопрос при работе с CNN, пожалуйста, помогите, это очень важно для меня.
Вопрос в комментариях под видео:
https://youtu.be/N4Bk2N95CKQ

Сам вопрос:
30:06 почему свёртка уменьшает изображение на 2 пикселя?

Я, спрашиваю тут, чтобы не писать сюда кучу слоёв нейронной сети. 30:06 это то время, когда на экране появился model.summary().

Comment: А почему спрашивать тут, а не в комментариях под самим роликом на ютубе? Врят-ли кто до вас тут смотрел 30 минут этого видео. Вы предлагаете нам это сделать? Или это такая ненавязчивая рекалама?

Comment: Я, спрашиваю тут, чтобы не писать сюда кучу слоёв нейронной сети. 30:06 это то время, когда на экране появился model.summary().

Comment: Выскажу предположение, что там был использован слой MaxPool2D, который уменьшает размер изображения в зависимости от своего ядра.